# incomplete markup or missing document element at offset 0 at http://blah.blah:9090 in datapower

Tags: websphere, ibm-datapower

Getting the error incomplete markup or missing document element at offset 0 at http://blah.blah:9090 in datapower when I tried testing with JSON request. MPG service has request and response type as Non-xml and I'm trying to log a detailed error message by fetching the json object value. So I have written an xslt for this in error rule. It's an existing service so can't change the request/response type so I'm currently stuck with the above error. Can someone please help to fix this issue.

JSON request:

`{ "meta": { "totalPages": 13 }`

I'm stuck with this error. Hope I get help here to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Json Request is invalid:
{ "meta": { "totalPages": 13 }} --> this valid json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).